# Android Toolbar Shadow is not showing for child activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Iam not able to show the shadow effect in child activity as like parent activity.

In Parent activity iam using CustomView
In Child coordinator layout is using.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you targeting API >= 21 ?

Comment: yes my target api is 22

Answer (score 0):

add this view below toolbar or appbar or where you want to show shadow.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
```

------- toolbar_dropshadow.xml------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#88333333"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:elevation` to the `Toolbar` if your targeting Android 5.0 and above or for pre-lollipop do the following.

**Toolbar.xml**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**shadow.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/no_color"
        android:endColor="@color/shadow_normal"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

**color.xml**

```
<color name="shadow_normal">#55000000</color>
<color name="no_color">#00000000</color>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to add this view programmatically

Comment: Wat is your actual requirement ? Where you have to add programmatically and why ?

Comment: I have a custom view that extends Toolbar, In that where I should add this view?

Comment: What is the purpose behind creating the custom toolbar view ? You can add the view right below like you added the toolbar.or post your code.

Comment: View shadowView = new View(this);
            view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(View Group.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, DeviceInfo.getValuesInDp(8));
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            toolbar.addView(shadowView, params);

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use elevation property android:elevation

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21), Use a view with shadow background inside a framelayout below the toolbar

eg given below

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/my_action_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity content here.... -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_toolbar_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />
</FrameLayout>
```

in the activity code, you can hide the shadow view if sdk version >=21

```
View mToolbarShadow = findViewById(R.id.view_toolbar_shadow);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mToolbarShadow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```